# git reset --hard hangs on CircleCI/Ubuntu 14 with git-lfs < 1.5.6

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, circleci, git-lfs

I'm deploying to CircleCI and but my code is timing out.

The command in particular that CircleCI is calling that's causing the time-out is during the `checkout` stage:

> git reset --hard SHA

Where `SHA` is the hash of the build, but upon ssh'ing in I noted that `HEAD` and others that I tried also run forever.

At that point the code has been checked out with:

> git clone --quiet git@github.com:Organization/Repo.git . --config core.compression=9 --depth 10 --no-single-branch

Why would `git reset --hard` run (seemingly) forever on the CircleCI environment, and what fixes are reasonably available?

More details (we've got some git-lfs files here, too):

- lsb-release Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- git version 2.11.0
- git-lfs/1.5.4 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.7.4)

**EDIT** This appears related to:

- github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/1932 (per @torek's comment)
- https://discuss.circleci.com/t/is-there-any-way-to-disable-git-lfs-in-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-image/10208/12

I would also note that adding `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1` (in the CircleCI Project config) has not had any useful effect.

It does help to go back to Ubuntu 12, but obviously that's less than ideal.

**EDIT**

Here's a recent bug report I filed: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/cannot-pull-with-git-lfs/14346

(Just to ensure visibility, because my other reports were buried in comments)

Comment: Probably the Git-LFS 1.5.x bug fixed in 1.5.6: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/1932

Comment: @torek Thanks. I'm thinking then that the best answer here is to pick a docker image for CircleCI that has git-lfs 1.5.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was a typo, namely that CircleCI was running version 1.0, but should have been using 2.0.

In particular, I had created a `.circleci/config.yaml`, with the appropriate config.

... however, it should've been called `.circleci/config.yml`.